Neo 5.x: New setting "Entry Type" -> What is the purpose or intended use of this feature?
Neo 5.x hat a new option for field settings called Entry Type (Choose the entry type this block type will take its name, handle, color, and field layout from.)
Honestly, I have no idea how this option would be useful in practice. :/
Does anyone have a quick example or simple use case for this?

